# Rails 3: how to reverse ERB "<%=" default behaviour so I can inject HTML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sanitization, erb

My question relates to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448860/what-does-h-means-in-rails), but I am trying to reverse the default Rails 3 behavior of "<%=" so that I can inject HTML.

In my scenario, I have an old Rails 2 plug that generates HTML. My view will then need to inject this HTML in the page.

When this plugin creates HTML like this stored in a variable `html_to_show`:

```
<p class="notice"><span></span>Sorry about this, but we have a problem...</p><p class="error"><span></span>Cannot go to next step</p>
```

and in the view I try to show the contents of `html_to_show` like this:

```
<%= html_to_show %>
```

... what I get in my browser is this:

```
&lt;p class="notice"&gt;&lt;span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;Sorry about this, but we have a problem...&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p class="error"&gt;&lt;span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;Cannot go to next step&lt;/p&gt;
```

How can I get Rails 3 to inject the contents of `html_to_show` exactly as it is, without any sanitization?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer:

```
<%= html_to_show.html_safe %>
```

Long answer:

Rails escapes all html to protect from XSS attacks. Adding `.html_safe` prevents the escaping.

Comment: @futureshocked: For the record: both the `html_safe` string method and the `raw` helper-style method do the same job, ultimately. If you want to update your plugin, though, you can mark the string as `html_safe` before it gets to your view and you don't need to do it again. If you append a non-html-safe string to it, though, it becomes non-safe and will need to be marked again.

Answer (score 3):

```
<%= raw html_to_show %>
```

That should do it.